# Specify max constraint percentage on a view

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

### Problem

Specify Max Constraint percentage for any view.

For example -

In a case below I have a 2 left views and 2 right views.

- I want to constraint that right can acquire maximum of 50% percent of the entire width.
- The left items holds precedence which means they can acquire as much space they like. So, if any of the left item is large enough it can shift right items and shrink them down.

I tried the following approach but this doesn't seem to work i.e when `right1` or `right2` text gets long enough it takes the preference and acquires more than 50% width.

Currently, constraint layout probably doesn't support this but is there any way to achieve this?

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/section_item_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/left_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/l_container"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        tools:text="Leftsadasdasdadsdasdasdhsjakjdhaskkjdhdjakskjhkjdashkjddasdasdsaadsdasd1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/l_container"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/left_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/left_1"
        tools:text="Left2" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/right_barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="start"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="l_container" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/right_2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
            tools:text="Right1"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/left_2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/right_1"
            tools:text="Right2"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53357276/6287910) work for you?

Comment: @Cheticamp This doesn't seem to work. This acquires a fixed width of 50% which I don't want bcz by default I want right items to be wrap and maximum stretch to 50%. 
Updated the question with the try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took some liberties to simplify the layout for this illustration, but you should be able to reconstruct your layout from the following.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/right_barrier"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Not so long" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/right_barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="start"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="right_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/right_barrier"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
        android:text="very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very " />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

which produces this:

[image]

Increasing the text length in `left_1` causes the left view encroach into the right half of the screen.

[image]

`layout_constrainedWidth` and `layout_constraintWidth_max` are what's of interest in the layout.